# Spring Boot 2.3 DataSource injection

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc

I have issues with recent Springboot 2.3 release.

I have the following config class:

```
package name.defance.springbootdemo.security;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
public class SampleConfig {

    @Autowired
    public SampleConfig(DataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.println("DATASOURCE: " + dataSource);
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    final private DataSource dataSource;
}
```

With version `2.2.7` I have the following output:

```
<... truncated output ...>
2020-05-18 17:57:33.872  INFO 2081 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-18 17:57:33.873  INFO 2081 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.34]
2020-05-18 17:57:33.950  INFO 2081 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-18 17:57:33.950  INFO 2081 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2113 ms
2020-05-18 17:57:34.511  INFO 2081 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-18 17:57:34.555  INFO 2081 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-05-18 17:57:34.686  INFO 2081 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-18 17:57:34.801  INFO 2081 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-18 17:57:34.901  INFO 2081 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-18 17:57:34.922  INFO 2081 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2020-05-18 17:57:35.405  INFO 2081 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-18 17:57:35.411  INFO 2081 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-18 17:57:35.463  WARN 2081 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : Unable to start LiveReload server
DATASOURCE: HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)
<... truncated output ...>
```

With version `2.3.0.RELEASE` I have the following:

```
<... truncated output ...>
2020-05-18 17:52:02.183  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-18 17:52:02.184  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.35]
2020-05-18 17:52:02.249  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-18 17:52:02.249  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2453 ms
2020-05-18 17:52:02.669  INFO 352 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
DATASOURCE: HikariDataSource (null)
2020-05-18 17:52:02.720  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-18 17:52:02.755  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
2020-05-18 17:52:02.862  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-18 17:52:02.957  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-18 17:52:03.066  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-18 17:52:03.081  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
2020-05-18 17:52:03.526  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-18 17:52:03.534  INFO 352 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-18 17:52:03.736  WARN 352 --- [         task-2] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : Unable to start LiveReload server
<... truncated output ...>
```

The only difference between those is (in `pom.xml`):

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

vs

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

So with the new release datasource bean is configured in a separate thread, and my configuration bean received not-yet configured DataSource bean (null).

I cannot find any reference to configuration flow changes in release notes. What is wrong here, and why my code stopped working?

*UPDATE*. I reproduced this issue once more with Spring initializer. Options selected: Java 14, actuator, jdbc, web, devtools, postgres db driver

Application properties contains all the correct connection data (verified on other old-spring project). Its only contents is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:15432/insurance-demo
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgresPWD
server.port=8080
```

*Update*: Project repo https://github.com/defance/datasource-demo

Comment: Did you configure application.properties and Database driver class is it available in class path?

Comment: I see also a separate thread but in my case it prints DATASOURCE: HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) Have you any other configuration?

Comment: Added some details into the question.

Comment: @LakshmanMiani, yes, datasource itself is valid, I am able to connect to it. With 2.2.7 I am also able to do some stuff vie DAO, etc...

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I created minimal configuration to reproduce the issue, added some libs via initializer: actuator, jdbc, web, devtools, postgres db driver. No extra config except datasource was made

Comment: Can you provide the code on GitHub? As I said I cannot reproduce the problem

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Sure. Here is my repo: https://github.com/defance/datasource-demo

Comment: @Autowired
    public SampleConfig(DataSource dataSource) {
        System.out.println("DATASOURCE: " + dataSource);
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
You are printing object before assigning.

Comment: Try this:
        this.dataSource = dataSource;System.out.println("DATASOURCE: " + dataSource);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa' can be added to the dependency set to bring the hikari pool start back to the same point it was before.

Using your repository, I added this section to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and the result:

```
2020-05-18 09:58:17.046  INFO 60543 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-18 09:58:17.094  INFO 60543 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
DATASOURCE: HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)
```

Here is the doc section about data source configuration that I followed:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-sql